# How to recode the duplicated, triple or more elements in the row in r

Tags: r

I have a data frame and in the row they are duplicated, triple or more value. I want to keep the first value and recode as Na or -2 the remain of element but, I have some issues. Can you help me?

[e.g of my data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwpVo.png)

I try with this r code:

N         <- nrow(data)

coln      <- paste0("x", 1:10)

for (i in 1:N) {

for (j in coln) {

```
   va <- which(table(dfriend[i, coln])>1)
   
   if (length(va)>0){
     data[i, j]   <- -2
   }

  else { 
    if (is.na(data[i, j]) {
    data[i, j]   <- -3
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: please provide your data as code, not images or links

Comment: you can use dput()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We could use `duplicated` (assuming if it is by column)

```
dfriend[coln] <- lapply(dfriend[coln], function(x) {
                          i1 <- is.na(x)
                          i2 <- duplicated(x)
                          x[i2] <- -2
                         x[i1] <- -3
                         x})
```

---

if we want to check replace by row, use `apply`

```
dfriend[coln] <- t(apply(dfriend[coln], 1, function(x) {
           i1 <- is.na(x)
                          i2 <- duplicated(x)
                          x[i2] <- -2
                         x[i1] <- -3
                         x}))
```